# Does NSS fully implement PKCS 11?

Tags: pkcs11

I am looking towards using NSS in a Linux application that makes use of a TPM (HSM). So, I am checking the support of [PKCS 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_11) in NSS, at least for the management of Elliptic Curve keys, signature with EC keys, RNG.

I read contradictory things. First, on the NSS site, it is said that only a subset of PKCS #11 is supported, and elsewhere, that it supports it natively as a mandatory layer. Then a software TPM is available for the case a hardware one is not available.

What is the status here? Does NSS fully implement PKCS 11, or only partially? If partially, is there a list of supported features somewhere, more friendly than reading the code?

Comment: This is a good question. Last time I checked it was not a fully compliant implementation - but I checked it a very long time ago. Note that NSS itself does support PKCS#11 *as internal engine* (otherwise smart cards wouldn't work). OTOH I'm not sure if a library question is a good fit for crypto...

Comment: Thanks owlstead. I tried to put it on *Information Security*, but it was said off-topic there. As far as I know, it would probably not fit Stackoverflow. So, which Stack would be good?

Comment: OK, keep it here then. You could all it an API matter (PKCS#11 is a C-interface), but I guess it is about cryptography as well. I already voted up, the question in itself is good.

Comment: The assertion "only a subset of PKCS #11 is supported" is [dating to 2008](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/nss-3.11/nss-3.11-algorithms.html) and concerns NSS v3.11.

Comment: From [upstream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/FAQ) : "NSS requires at least PKCS #11 version 2.0, but can support some features of later versions of NSS, including NSS 2.20. NSS does not use all the features of later versions of PKCS #11."

Comment: That's all about *using* the PKCS#11 interface for (smartcard etc) tokens. It's not about the NSS interface *itself*, to applications that use NSS. As far as I know, the NSS interface has many similarities with PKCS#11, but it doesn't declare all the functions of the PKCS#11 interface.

Comment: From the same: "Your token should expect to implement all the PKCS#11 functions that make sense for your token. NSS [...] periodically enhances it's functionality by using a more complete list of PKCS #11 functions. You should have implementations for all the functions specified in the version of the PKCS #11 spec your token implements. If you do not actually do the operation specified by that function, you can return CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED." I understand the driver SHALL implement all functions and return "I don't support it, do it yourself" when not supported. Looks like complete support

Comment: Great remark owlstead (our last messages have crossed one each other)

Comment: Note that e.g. the PKCS#11 provider of Oracle in Java does support NSS, but it does require additional configuration as well.

Comment: List of PKCS11 functions supported by NSS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11_Implement).

Comment: I would seriously think about using the well standardized PKCS#11 interface directly instead. Why do you want to use the subset of the functionality, hidden behind the proprietary API provided by NSS?

Comment: I need to make work Apache and OpenSSH with a TPM. Then every good solution is right. Apache has modules for OpenSSL, NSS, and GnuTLS, so one can easily choose. NSS and GnuTLS both support pkcs11. The support of NSS looks good. I have not yet survey the one of GnuTLS. On the contrary, the external module for OpenSSL is very poor (RSA only). For OpenSSH, I still not foresee any solution to use EC authentication in the TPM.

Comment: OK, but I don't see anything in your question that assumes that this is about *using* the PKCS#11 interface from NSS. Especially the title seems contradictory. And I think that your comment about the PKCS#11 functions supported by NSS basically answers your own question :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I will have to check the code. Actually, my main concern now is if OpenSSH can be built with NSS, but it is [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400471/how-to-build-openssh-with-nss-or-gnutls-instead-of-openssl)